# Testing whether item is visible in virtual ListView

Tags: .net, listview, ownerdrawn

I'm using a ListView control in virtual and OwnerDraw mode to display a number of items.
Is there a way to test whether a certain item is visible (within the client area of the control) without triggering a draw event or a RetrieveVirtualItem event?

The problem is, I have a background thread that periodically adds more items to the listview. But for some reason, every time I add more items (increment VirtualListSize), it triggers a RetrieveVirtualItem for the last item added, even though it's nowhere near the visible range.
And, of course, I only want to draw items that are actually visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: I thought the DrawItem event only gets fired for visible items.

Comment: No, it's definitely being fired every time I change VirtualListSize (for the last item in the list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On virtual lists, Windows fires `RetrieveVirtualItem` events in many strange places -- and they are different between XP, Vista and Win7. Owner drawn virtual lists are the worst.

If your goal is to reduce the number of `RetrieveVirtualItem` events, you are out of luck.

If your goal is to reduce the number of redraws necessary for your `OwnerDrawn` rows, you will be better off optimizing the redrawing more directly. For example, you can capture the rectangle of the damaged region in the `WM_PAINT` event, and then use that in your subitem drawing method to determine if that subitem was damaged.

Or you could use [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) -- an open source wrapper around a .NET WinForms ListView -- that has already dealt with this problem. If you are going to allow horizontal scrolling AND column rearranging, you *really* do want to use an ObjectListView -- for  reasons [explained here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog3.html).